# Я написал свой сканер портов на языке Rust при помощи библиотеке std::net. Почему У меня зависает программа если ввести другое значение

Tags: сеть, rust, сканирование-портов

Например если я изменю значение переменной `my_host` на 192.168.1.0 или на любой другой адрес, то программа просто перестанет отвечать как исправить данную проблему в приведенном коде ниже:

```
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn tcp_scan(host: String){
    for port in 1..1024{
        let mut ip = String::from(&host);
        ip.push_str(":");
        ip.push_str(&port.to_string());

        if let Ok(_) = TcpStream::connect(&ip){
            println!("This {} port is open", ip);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let my_host = String::from("192.168.1.0");
    tcp_scan(my_host);
}
```

Comment: Что-то не похоже, чтобы вы пытались предпринимать что-нибудь в случае, если сервер не захочет отвечать. Ну хотя бы [connect_timeout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.connect_timeout) например?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal connect_timeout у меня тоже не работал